# No module named 'sknn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am facing a problem with the sci kit neural network (sknn) module.

The code:

```
from sknn.mlp import Regressor, Layer

capasinicio = TodasEstaciones.loc['2015-01-12':'2015-03-31'].as_matrix()[:,[0,2]]
capasalida = TodasEstaciones.loc['2015-01-12':'2015-03-31'].as_matrix()[:,1]
neurones =  1000
tasaaprendizaje = 0.00001
numiteraciones = 9000


#Definition of the training for the neural network
redneural = Regressor(
    layers=[
        Layer("ExpLin", units=neurones), 
        Layer("ExpLin", units=neurones), Layer("Linear")],
    learning_rate=tasaaprendizaje,
    n_iter=numiteraciones)
redneural.fit(capasinicio, capasalida)

#Get the prediction for the train set
valortest = ([])

for i in range(capasinicio.shape[0]):
    prediccion = redneural.predict(np.array([capasinicio[i,:].tolist()]))
    valortest.append(prediccion[0][0])
```

The error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e1e3c4d6d246> in <module>()
----> 1 from sknn.mlp import Regressor, Layer
      2 
      3 capasinicio = TodasEstaciones.loc['2015-01-12':'2015-03-31'].as_matrix()[:,[0,2]]
      4 capasalida = TodasEstaciones.loc['2015-01-12':'2015-03-31'].as_matrix()[:,1]
      5 neurones =  1000

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sknn'
```

It appears that installing the module through pip

```
pip install scikit-neuralnetwork
```

does not solve the problem

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me: I uninstalled both python and anaconda, then reinstalled anaconda while specifying that its corresponding PATH gets the priority when calling modules (an option that is not recommended by the developers).